# Does Oracle discourage PHP from accessing MYSQL with PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have read nothing but good things about PHP's PDO library. Today in my reading I came across this [link](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/30-php-best-practices-for-beginners/#comment-690093767) that says Oracle discourages the use of PDO when accessing Mysql. The comment stated that PDO doesn't offer access to all the features that Mysql has to offer.

My question is this:

- Does Oracle discourage the use of PDO?
- If so, What features am I not able to access with PDO?

Comment: That's a two year old comment. I'd find something more recent with some references before trusting some random comment on the Internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there's anything PDO can't do. There are things php/mysql can't do that php/mysqli or PDO can. The only thing Oracle really pushes is that you use the [mysqlnd driver](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/php-mysqlnd/) with PHP (which is a good idea whether or not you use PDO)

Comment: I'm quite sure that PDO doesn't support some mysqlnd features, e.g. asynchronous queries and polling